# Thread safety with multiple MessageListeners using same onMessage?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

How can I ensure that two Listener containers:

```
<bean id="listenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="messageListener" ref="MessageListener" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="tcf" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${jms-topic}" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="listenerContainer-2"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="messageListener" ref="MessageListener" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="tcf" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${jms-topic-2}" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="MessageListener" class="com.my.url.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListener">
    <property name="transformer" ref="transformer" />
    <property name="publisher" ref="publisher" />
</bean>
```

That recieve messages from different topics. Are thread safe?

As you can see, they use the same Message Listener which is also reliant on some other spring beans. All messages will be received by the same onMessage Method in the same class.

```
public class SomeKlass implements MessageListener {


    public void onMessage(Message message) {        
            //Do some work
    }

}
```

Can someone advise me on the best practice for this kind of problem. Messages from both topics need to be handled in the same way so I only need one MessageListener.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely fine as long as you don't have any state in `SomeKlass` which you don't appear to have.

Comment: Thanks but can you elaborate on this for me? There is a lot of processing inside the onMessage method in reality. I took it out for the purpose of this Question. I will edit and add some more info.

Comment: It is shared state which creates issues with threading - if there had been an instance variable inside `SomeKlass`, then this variables state could have been modified by multiple threads and would have resulted in Thread safety issues. Since you do not have any instance variables in `SomeKlass`, your onMessage is thread safe - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187943/are-local-variables-within-static-methods-thread-safe for a related question